# How to get the duration of the audio recorded using flutter_sound package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter_sound package for Audio recording. I want to ge the duration of the recorded audio, to send it through an API and also display it in the UI. So, how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I was using [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) package in my project. So I managed to get the total duration of the audio using the package.

```
  Future<int> _getAudioduration(String audioPath) async {
    final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    await audioPlayer.setUrl(audioPath, isLocal: true);

    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => audioPlayer.getDuration(),
    );
  }
```

*****There may be another solutions for getting the total duration of an audio. This may not be the proper solution. I am posting this here so that someone might find this helpful***